# scroll bar for listviews in tables for android using phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, iscroll

I'm working on android tablet using phonegap. In my application i divided my html into two vertical parts which contains list views and i 'm filling those list views with data coming from different services. I want to add separate scrollers for each listview so that i can scroll only listview but not the hole page. I tried using iscroller but that css is effecting my existing UI. So can anyone show other ways to get this scrollers? or iscroller without using css? anything is fine. can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the experimental jquery mobile scrollview https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/experiments/scrollview

The GitHub repo includes a couple of examples to show how to use it.